# What is the best way to ignore a leading slash when resolving a java.nio.files.Path

Tags: java, nio, filepath

I'm trying to refactor some legacy code using `java.io.File` to use `java.nio.file.Path` instead.

I'm bitten by the fact that Path has better support for absolute filepaths, because a lot of the values I receive have a leading slash (`/`) while they are supposed to represent relative paths. String concatenation is easier that way but I'm trying to move away from `String`/`File` to represent filepaths.

The old behaviour was that `new File(parent, child)` returned a new `File` representing

- a child file/directory under the parent directory, regardless of whether child started with `/`.

The new behaviour was that `parent.resolve(child)` returned a new `Path` representing either

- a child file/directory under the parent directory
- child as the root (if it started with `/`)

I think the new way can allow for cleaner code, but when refactoring a legacy application it can introduce subtle bugs.

**What is the best/cleanest way to get back the old (`File`) behaviour while using `Path`?**

---

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    file();
    path();
  }

  public static void file(){
    File root = new File("/root");
    File relative = new File(root, "relative");
    File absolute = new File(root, "/absolute");

    System.out.println("File:");
    System.out.println(relative.getAbsolutePath()); // prints "/root/relative"
    System.out.println(absolute.getAbsolutePath()); // prints "/root/absolute"
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void path(){
    Path root = Paths.get("/root");
    Path relative = root.resolve("relative");
    Path absolute = root.resolve("/absolute");

    System.out.println("Path:");
    System.out.println(relative.toAbsolutePath()); // prints "/root/relative"
    System.out.println(absolute.toAbsolutePath()); // prints "/absolute" but should print "/root/absolute"
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

---

Basically what I want is a method that takes a parent Path, and a child String that returns me the parent+child Path regardless of whether the child had a leading `/`.
Something like this, but without the String manipulations that depend on me knowing that the configuration will use `/` (and not `\`):

```
private static Path resolveSafely(Path parent, String child) {
    child = child.startsWith("/")
            ? child.substring(1)
            : child;
    parent.resolve(child);
}
```

Comment: `absolute.getRoot().relativize(absolute))` is one way to drop the root component in this example.

Comment: Not quite what I want (the result doesn't contain the parent anymore, and can fail as `getRoot()` is `null` when the `/` is absent).  I edited the question to make the expectations more clear.

Comment: Just on the method name in your question. "resolveSafely" is not a good name because it's more like concat than resolve. The resolve methods that Path defines do the right thing, the 2-arg File construction is more like concat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I could find is this:

```
    Path root = Paths.get("/root");
    Path relative = root.resolve("relative");
    Path absolute = Paths.get(root.toString(), "/absolute");

    System.out.println("Path:");
    System.out.println(relative.toAbsolutePath()); // prints "/root/relative"
    System.out.println(absolute.toAbsolutePath()); // prints "/root/absolute"
    System.out.println();
```

Hopefully that's all you need.

Edit: Since Java 11, `Path.of()` is available and is the recommended way of obtaining Path objects instead of `Paths.get()`. [Check javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html) which also states that `Paths` class may be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: I didn't realize the behaviour of `Paths.get` is different than the behaviour of `Path.resolve`. This is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks.